# How to add Indian timezone to Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

i'm trying to find out what's the easiest way to add India Standard Time (+0530 from utc) to postgresql (9.1).

i tried the silly thing of trying to insert it into the table, but it doesn't work.

> insert into pg_timezone_abbrevs values('INDIA','05:30:00');

the problem what detected years ago by other people, [Googling](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4983.1075569542@sss.pgh.pa.us) in old mailing lists tells me. but not simple solution found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Buttom line**:
don't use *IST*, that's Israel time zone, not Indian time zone. use '*Asia/Kolkata*'. instead.

Postgres documentation of this is vague, but notice that looking at:

> SELECT name, abbrev, utc_offset, is_dst FROM pg_timezone_names;

will give you different options that those of, not showing all the available timezones.

> SELECT abbrev, utc_offset, is_dst FROM pg_timezone_abbrevs;

and editing this file doesn't have any effect. don't bother. perhaps you need to manually change another config to include it.

> /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/timezonesets/Asia.txt

Comment: Actually, `IST` *is* India time… and Israel time… and Ireland time… and maybe more. These 3-4 character pseudo zones are *not* actual time zones, *not* standardized, and ***not* unique** (as seen here). **Avoid these pseudo-zones** like the Plague. Real time zones are named in format of `continent/region` such as `Europe/Paris`, [`Asia/Kolkata`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia/Kolkata), and `Pacific/Auckland`. See: [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)